# Как создать iframe приложение в Facebook

Tags: вконтакте, facebook, app

Как создать приложение iframe в fb как в вк?

Хоть куда копать?

Comment: Закрывашкам: на англоязычном SO даже метка есть [facebook-iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-iframe). Похоже, что вопрос вполне решаемый.

Comment: Хороший ответ мог бы содержать пошаговый туториал по написанию Hello World для фейсбука. Если задача оказывается слишком большой, повысьте уровень абстракции. Например: 1) зарегистрируйте акк разработчика на фб 2) напишите код по инструкции: ссылка 3) задеплойте приложение на сервер по инструкции: ссылка 4) профит.

Comment: Евгений, комментарий не вам адресован, а тому кто захочет ответить.